# how to close the edges between an input and span html element?

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui

I have an issue related with an html elements which doesn't close the gap between an `<input>` and `<span>` element.  As seen on the screenshot (highlighted in red box) below.

[image]

I'm not sure if `<input>` and `<span>` elements can be used together to achieve a drop down list like control - an input box on the left-hand side and, a button on the right-hide side as one control.

A code snippet of `<span>` element which wraps the `<input>` and `<span>` elements.

```
<span class="k-state-default">
                <input type="text" id="scheduler" placeholder="Click arrow to create schedule" class="k-input">
                <span class="k-select" id="btn-scheduler" onclick="showSchedulerPanel()" role="button">
                    <span class="k-icon k-i-clock"></span>
                </span>
            </span>
```

I couldn't find any related issues in SO, if you know a link please feel free to comment and mark this question as duplicate.

I have put up a fiddle to illustrate the problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/jun1uz/365bt4qp/4/

Any inputs, suggestions or violent reaction is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would go with

```
#btn-scheduler {
   position:relative;
   left:-5px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing your thoughts.  Why would `position: relative` did the trick? Isn't it `<span>` element is an inline-block element will normally render besides any element?